# How do I pull a set of data from my array and create a new array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a 'No Code' App to build a small web app, but I have a couple of issues with it that I am trying to fix. As you can expect, I have very little experience with javascript but I hope somebody can help.

I have an array of data for which I would like to create a short code which will create a second array 'firstnames' which will pull out the "firstday" as below

First array:

```
info = ["id": 1, "firstname": FN1, "lastname": LN1
"id": 2, "firstname": FN2, "lastname": LN2
"id": 3, "firstname": FN3, "lastname": LN3 etc...]
```

Desired second array:

```
firstnames = [FN1, FN2, FN3 etc...]`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have tried some 'for' loops, but I could not seem to make the outcome only show the single value in the array.

```
const firstnames = [];
let i = 0;
for (i < info.length; i++) {
firstnames.push(firstname[i]);
}`
```

Comment: Your first "array" is not an array. That syntax is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: It seems that I missed the bracket {} from each object